# How to get unique records based on one column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in which `subscription_id` is used multiple times, every month a customer charged  an order to be generated with same data & unique order id so there is a column 'updated_at' which also updates so I want to get only one (1) latest record from table based on subscription_id, I am using following query, but it's not working and getting old record.

```
SELECT *
FROM members_subscriptions
WHERE status = 'active'
GROUP BY subscription_id
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

Can any one tell me what's wrong with this query ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need get the `MAX()` of `updated_at` , order by runs after grouping so you need to compare with the newest date

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM members_subscriptions
WHERE status = 'active'
AND updated_at IN(
SELECT MAX(updated_at) 
FROM members_subscriptions 
GROUP BY subscription_id
)
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.* 
FROM members_subscriptions m 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT subscription_id, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at
  FROM members_subscriptions GROUP BY subscription_id
) AS maxdatte USING (subscription_id, updated_at);
```

Comment: Actually I think one has to compare the `subscription_id` inside of the subquery too. The query above will work most of the time, since it is unlikely that the exact same timestamp is contained in two rows, but if this is the case, the query does not work as expected.

Comment: @GhostGambler updated my answer with a join example also

Answer (score 1):

Assumming that each subsciption can have only unique dates in `updated_at`, then this query should give desired result:

```
SELECT *
FROM members_subscriptions
WHERE status = 'active'
AND (subscription_id, updated_at) IN(
    SELECT subscription_id, MAX(updated_at) 
    FROM members_subscriptions 
    GROUP BY subscription_id
)
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

But if one subscription may have more that one same dates, then the query must use unique `id` to get only one record from two or more with the same date:

```
SELECT *
FROM members_subscriptions m
WHERE status = 'active'
  AND id = (
      SELECT id FROM members_subscriptions m1
      WHERE m.subscription_id = m1.subscription_id
        AND status = 'active'
      ORDER BY updated_at DESC
      LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that result is first being grouped and only then ordered. If you need latest result, you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
   FROM members_subscriptions as main
   WHERE status = `active` AND `updated_at` = (
       SELECT MAX(`updated_at`) FROM members_subscriptions as sub
       WHERE status='active' and main.`subscription_id` = sub.`subscription_id`
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct (name)
FROM members_subscriptions
WHERE status = 'active'
GROUP BY subscription_id
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

use distinct with field name you want to find